# vector.erase(begin(vector)) will remove LAST element of vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, erase

The following

```
void PlayListModel::removeTrack(int track) //does not work
{
    qDebug()<<track;
    assert(track >= 0);
    if (not mTracks.empty() and static_cast<int>(track) < mTracks.size())
    {
        auto iterator = begin(mTracks) + track;
        qDebug()<<iterator->getName();
        mTracks.erase(iterator);
        emit NeedRefreshView();
    }
}
```

will always remove the last element of the mTracks (of type std::vector), although iterator points to the correct element.

My AudioTrackModel operators and constructors:

```
AudioTrackModel::AudioTrackModel(const QString& path) :
mPath(path),
mFile(path)
{
    qDebug()<<"loaded file"<<" "<<path;
    TagHandler TagHandler(path);
    if (TagHandler.hasTags() == false)
    {
        mName = mFile.baseName();
    } else {
        storeName(TagHandler.getTitle());
        storeArtist(TagHandler.getArtist());
        mDiscNumber = TagHandler.getDisc();
        mTrackNumber = TagHandler.getTrack();
        storeAlbum(TagHandler.getAlbum());
        qDebug()<<"Track number is"<<mTrackNumber;
        qDebug()<<"Disc number is"<<mDiscNumber;
    }
    mDuration = TagHandler.getDuration();
}

AudioTrackModel::AudioTrackModel(AudioTrackModel&& other) :
mName(other.mName),
mPath(other.mPath),
mFile(other.mFile),
mDuration(other.mDuration),
mDiscNumber(other.mDiscNumber),
mAlbum(other.mAlbum),
mArtist(other.mArtist),
mTrackNumber(other.mTrackNumber),
mCurrent(other.mCurrent)
{
}

AudioTrackModel::AudioTrackModel(const AudioTrackModel& other) :
mName(other.mName),
mPath(other.mPath),
mFile(other.mFile),
mDuration(other.mDuration),
mDiscNumber(other.mDiscNumber),
mAlbum(other.mAlbum),
mArtist(other.mArtist),
mTrackNumber(other.mTrackNumber),
mCurrent(other.mCurrent)
{
}

AudioTrackModel& AudioTrackModel::operator=(AudioTrackModel&& other)
{
    mPath =other.mPath;
    mFile = other.mFile;
    mDuration = other.mDuration;
    mDiscNumber = other.mDiscNumber;
    mAlbum = other.mAlbum;
    mArtist = other.mArtist;
    mTrackNumber = other.mTrackNumber;
    mCurrent = other.mCurrent;
    return *this;
}

AudioTrackModel& AudioTrackModel::operator=(const AudioTrackModel& other)
{
    mPath =other.mPath;
    mFile = other.mFile;
    mDuration = other.mDuration;
    mDiscNumber = other.mDiscNumber;
    mAlbum = other.mAlbum;
    mArtist = other.mArtist;
    mTrackNumber = other.mTrackNumber;
    mCurrent = other.mCurrent;
    return *this;
}
```

This issue is driving me crazy, i have no idea what's happening.

Comment: Why don't you debug it and at least print vector size and `track` value?

Comment: `auto iterator = begin(mTracks) + track;` What's the value of `track` and how big is the vector?

Comment: Might not be related to your problem, but your move constructor doesn't move anything so there's no reason to have it.

Comment: Include in your sscce.org code that 'fails' because it was the last elememt that was erased, and not the first.  In short, how do you know it was the last element?  A pointer?  A reference?  An iterator?

Comment: Works for me:  http://ideone.com/3WDf03